# Why Does Making my div into a circle affect bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website and I am trying to make use of the grid/column system provided in bootstrap. What I want to do is have a picture on the left side with the text beside it to the right. This is the html that I have written so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 circle-pic">
            <!-- circle -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            words and stuff go here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css that I've written so far:

```
.circle-pic {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

My problem is that the first div is not taking up 4 columns as I expect it too which is causing it these elements to be uncentered. I think the problem occurring because I specified the width and height for the circle and that is overwriting something in col-xs-4. Is that the case? If so, how would I go about centering these elements? If not then, Why is the circle not taking up 4 columns worth of space?

EDIT: I am using bootstrap 3.2.0. I have tested on safari and chrome and I do not have any custom rules for col-xs-4.

Comment: What css rules do you have in col-xs-4 ?

Comment: Which edition of Bootstrap are you using. Which browsers are you testing with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the border radius will not affect the table style.

The width will. It will force the div to be 150px wide on every resolution which will make it not responsive anymore.

Bootstrap has [a feature](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) for showing round pictures. You can doing that like this:

```
<img src="..." alt="My image" class="img-circle">
```

Comment: Thanks Anton. I didn't know that was something bootstrap provided.